# Select drop down webkit appearance in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, frontend

Making a simple drop down with select tag, chrome uses their default list container. How do I remove the defaults?

```
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}
```

Comment: You can read [this article](https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/select-css.html). It will help you style default selects.

Comment: you cannot "remove" them. you have to overwrite the defaults with your own style rules.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried styling it after setting the appearance to none? Usually appearance: none should already resolve the issue.

EDIT: Tried it quickly myself and for me appearance: none; resolves the issue. Does the problem still persist and did you link the css file?

Comment: Yes, thank you, the styling does come after the appearance none.

Comment: sorry I meant that it already is styled like that and still doesn't fix the issue..

Comment: Oh ok, did you check if the css filed is linked correctly?

Comment: Oh you meant the list itself did you? not the actuall select tag but the option tags. Yeah you cant. Appearance:none only affects the select element but not the option-list